# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method imagem::Exibir()

Tags: php

estou começando a estudar PHP, estou tentando fazer com que o caminho da imagem apareça, porém retorna o seguinte erro:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method imagem::Exibir() in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\home.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Paginas.class.php(17): include() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\site\index.php(123): Paginas->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\home.php on line 20**

***Class rotas:***

```
<?php


class Rotas{

static $pastaFotos = 'fotos/';
static $siteUrl = 'http://localhost/site/';


static $index = 'index.php';
static $detalhe = '?pag=detalhe&item';
 }
```

***Class imagem:***

```
<?php


 class Imagem {


public static function Exibir($imagem, $w, $h){

    $fotos = Rotas::$siteUrl . Rotas::$pastaFotos ;

    echo $fotos;

}

     public static function Upload() {

    }

  }
```

***home:***

```
<?php


   $portfolio = new Conexao();



     $portfolio->ExecSQL("select * from trabalhos");


      while($ptf = $portfolio->ListarDados()){


       echo $ptf['trabalhos_titulo'] . '<br>';
        echo Imagem::Exibir('sss', '34', '34');


      }
```

Obrigada desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Soluções:

Para você ter acesso a uma classe, você tem que incluir na página onde você quer chamar. Para isso você pode utilizar um dos 4 métodos:

#### 1. `include` e `require`

Com essas funções você poderá incluir arquivos no seu projeto. Você só precisa definir o caminho do arquivo, mas atenção: *Os arquivos são incluídos baseando-se no caminho do arquivo informado ou, se não informado, o include_path especificado.*

Caso você precise modificar o `include_path`, basta utilizar o código `ini_set("include_path", "/path/to");`

#### 2. `include_once` e `require_once`

Essas funções são idênticas as anteriores, a diferença é que o `PHP` irá verificar se o arquivo já foi incluso no projeto, caso já tenha sido incluso, ignora.

Caso o arquivo não exista, as funções retornarão um erro.

---

#### Utilizando as funções em seu projeto

No seu arquivo *home.php*, basta incluir o seguinte código:

```
require_once "class_image.php";
```

Pronto, seu arquivo *home.php* já tem acesso à classe `Image`.

---

#### Utilizando as funções de forma automática

Para carregar esses arquivos de forma automática, você poderá utilizar a função [spl_autoload_register](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Dessa forma, toda vez que você criar ou instanciar um objeto, o `php` adicionará essa função do `spl_autoload`, verificará se o arquivo existe, e incluirá em seu projeto *(caso o arquivo exista)*.

Para isso basta utilizar o seguinte código no *home.php* ou *index.php*. O código valerá para todas as outras páginas que venham ser adicionadas tendo como base esses arquivos.

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {    
    $class .= ".php";    
    if (file_exists($class)) {
        require_once "classes/{$class}";
    } else {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("File {$class} not exists.");
    }
});

Imagem::Exibir();
```

> Basta adicionar a classe `Imagem` dentro da pasta *classes*. Lembrando que o nome da classe, deverá ser o mesmo nome do arquivo.

> Dica: Utilize sempre o caminho completo do arquivo.

Comment: MUITO obrigada me ajudou muito

Comment: MUITO obrigada me ajudou muito